# How require options for CLI app based on Python and Click

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I am building a CLI app with Python and the Click library.

How do I achieve the following use case:

First I only want the subcommand to be followed by an argument no options are required:

```
$ myapp subcommand argument
```

This is straight forward.

But how can I write the code that if argument2 is set that also some options are required?

```
$ myapp subcommand argument2 -o1 abc -o2 def
```

For example:

no options are required:

```
$ ./myapp.py install basic
```

options are required:

```
$ ./myapp.py install custom -o1 abc -o2 def
```

Furthermore I do not know how to make choice for arguments, that means that the user must choose between "basic" or "custom". In case he chooses "custom", he needs to add some options.

Comment: Did you add `required=True` ? https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#parameters

Comment: Yes, but this does not solve my issue. I want that only if argument2 is passed, the options are necessary. I will update my question

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far, to see what you've tried exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have achieved this successfully by making your `argument2` be a `click.Command`.
Running through the code below, my main way of interacting with the CLI application is via the `cli` group. That `cli` group has another group, `install`, added as a command. So we have a CLI with nested groups.
`install` has 2 commands, `basic` and `custom`, as in your example.

`basic` takes no parameters, while `custom` takes 2 required `Options`.

Calls would look like this:

```sh
❯ myapp install custom -o1 arg1 -o2 def
This is a custom install with option1: arg1 and option2: def

❯ myapp install basic
Executing a basic install
```

You can see the nested group `install` acts as a command inside the help message:

```
❯ myapp
Usage: myapp [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  install
```

And if you were to invoke `install`, this is the help output you'd get.

```
❯ myapp install
Usage: myapp install [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  basic
  custom
```

This is the code:

```py
import click


@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


@click.group()
def install():
    pass


@install.command()
def basic():
    print('Executing a basic install')


@install.command()
@click.option("-o1", "--option1", required=True)
@click.option("-o2", "--option2", required=True)
def custom(option1, option2):
    print(f'This is a custom install with option1: {option1} and option2: {option2}')


def main():
    cli.add_command(install)
    cli()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: That worked ;). Did not know that we can use more than 1 group.